# is Search-based algorithms and Genetic Algorithms the same?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I'm learning about Genetic algorithms and procedural content generation and in some papers people talk about Search-based algorithms to create content such as levels.

Anyway, I'm reading some papers about the topic and in some of them talk about Search-based algorithms and basically they explain what it is, and for me looks basically like a genetic algorithm, but I'm not really sure if they're the same, or a particular case of genetic algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the other way around. Genetic Algorithms are **a kind of** search-based algorithm. In GA you are **searching** inside the universe of possible solutions, getting better at doing the job by combining parts of the successful solutions (and a bit of chance: mutation).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search-based_software_engineering